# Leading inputs must be numeric. Matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, fuzzy

Im recieving an error that I dont understand using FCM.

If I set options like it mentions in the [Documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/fuzzy/fcm.html) it outputs this error:

```
??? Error using ==> zeros
Leading inputs must be numeric.

Error in ==> fcm at 83
obj_fcn = zeros(max_iter, 1);   % Array for objective function

Error in ==> fcm at 82
      [centers, U, objFun] = fcm(data, 6, 'options');
```

If I remove the options the code runs fine, here is the full code:

```
  [centers, U, objFun] = fcm(data, 6, 'options');
  plot(data(:,1), data(:,2),'o');
  maxU = max(U);
  index1 = find(U(1, :) == maxU);
  index2 = find(U(2, :) == maxU);
  line(data(index1,1),data(index1, 2),'linestyle','none',...
 'marker','*','color','g');
  line(data(index2,1),data(index2, 2),'linestyle','none',...
 'marker', '*','color','r');
```

Comment: What is the value of `max_iter` when this happens? Try inserting a line saying `disp(max_iter)` just before the call to `zeros` to check what the value is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `fcm` expects to receive an options *array*, not a string. You're passing `'options'`, but instead, you should do something like this:

```
options(1) = 2.0;
options(2) = 100;
options(3) = 1e-5;
options(4) = 1;
[centers, U, objFun] = fcm(data, 6, options); % notice no quotes!
```

I'm using the default values specified in the `fcm` documentation. You may change them to whatever you like.

Alternatively, the documentation specifies that if you want the default value, you can just set the option to `NaN`, so feel free to do that for whatever options you want defaults for.